# Stuck with this integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1x^k\log(1+x^n)dxdk$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to evaluate
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1x^k\log(1+x^n)\ dx\ dk$$
because I hope it has a closed form. No reason to be sure of it though.

Since evaluating the inside integral before left me stuck because couldn't integrate the result, I tried to switch the order of integration, only to get
$$\int_0^1\frac{x-1}{\log x}\log(1+x^n)\ dx$$
which, to me, seems even harder.
I also remember having seen once an expansion for $\log(1+x^n)$ involving Stirling's numbers of the first kind, but couldn't find it online. I think, however, this is useless in order to get a closed form.

Comment: Equivalent to $\int_0^1\int_0^1 (t^{1+(k+1)/n})\ln(1+t)dt dk$ if I'm not mistaken. Does $\int_0^1 t^q\ln(1+t)dt$ have a closed form for noninteger $q$?

Comment: Did you try integration by parts to deal with a rational function instead?

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes, I think it does just by expanding the log series. How did you get the result though? $x^n \to x$?

Comment: $x\rightarrow t^{1/n}$

Comment: @Pedro yes I integrated the inner integral completely, but got an ugly think impossible to integrate

Comment: $$I(n)=\int_0^1\int_0^1x^k\log(1+x^n)\ dx\ dk=\int_0^1\left(\psi\big(1+\frac{1+k}n\big)-\psi\big(1+\frac{1+k}{2n}\big)\right)\frac{dk}{1+k}$$
$$=\int_1^2\left(\psi\big(1+\frac xn\big)-\psi\big(1+\frac x{2n}\big)\right)\frac{dx}x$$
I don't think that the closed form exists.

Comment: @Svyatoslav. I did not see you comment before posting my answer. Sorry for that. Cheers

Comment: In my opinion, switching the order f integration makes the problem worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am very skeptical about a possible closed form since, depending on the manner you attack the inner integral
$$I(k)=\int_0^1x^k\,\log(1+x^n)\, dx$$ it write
$$I(k)=\frac{\log (2)-\Phi \left(-1,1,\frac{k+n+1}{n}\right)}{k+1}\tag 1$$ where appears  the Lerch transcendent function  or
$$I(k)=\frac {\gamma +2 \log (2) +\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{k+n+1}{2 n}\right)-H_{\frac{k+1}{2 n}}}{2(k+1)}\tag 2$$ where appear the digamma function and a generalized harmonic number (both of them with non integer arguments).

Using $(2)$, we can write
$$\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{k+n+1}{2 n}\right)-H_{\frac{k+1}{2 n}}=\left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{n+1}{2 n}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2 n+1}{2 n}\right)-\gamma \right)+$$
$$\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac {\psi ^{(p)}\left(\frac{n+1}{2 n}\right)-\psi ^{(p)}\left(\frac{2
   n+1}{2 n}\right) }{2^p\,p!\,n^p }\,k^p$$ and use
$$\int_0^1 \frac {k^p}{k+1}\, dk=\frac{1}{2} \left(H_{\frac{p}{2}}-H_{\frac{p-1}{2}}\right)$$

Trying for $n=5$ and computing the partial sums
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{summation} \\
 0 & 0.09337735 \\
 1 & 0.12717582 \\
 2 & 0.12326392 \\
 3 & 0.12376502 \\
 4 & 0.12369740 \\
 5 & 0.12370683 \\
 6 & 0.12370548 \\
 7 & 0.12370568 \\
 8 & 0.12370565 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$